# First appearance of tensor product symbol $\otimes$

Tags: notation, linear-algebra

I was asked recently if the tensor product symbol $\otimes$ had been used before Bourbaki's publication on multilinear algebra in 1948 (a draft of this document can be seen at http://sites.mathdoc.fr/archives-bourbaki/PDF/040_iecnr_049.pdf starting on p. 10). I was unable to find any earlier usage, so that leads to my question:

> Who introduced the symbol $\otimes$ for use in tensor products?

Comment: While we're at it,  when was that exact same symbol used to indicate a basis vector pointing "down into the page" in  vector diagrams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keith:

The earliest usage we have been able to find is in a 1936 paper by Francis J Murray and John von Neumann, entitled "Rings of Operators"(Annals of Mathematics, Vol. 37, pp. 116-229). Paul Halmos later used it in the earliest published version of his "Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces," published by Princeton University Press in 1942 (see Appendix II-Direct Products).

Jim Casey

Comment: Ok, so we have an earlier reference.   Does that book  indicate whether the symbol was invented by the author (or that he got it from somewhere else)?

Comment: Keith and I located an earlier occurrence in a paper by Murray and von Neumann, "On Rings of Operators," published in 1936.

Comment: Cool -- you should edit your answer to reflect that.