# History: Direct Product became Tensor Product?

Tags: mathematics, terminology

I'm reading a 1939 paper by the great and famous J. von Neumann, "On infinite direct products" (of vector spaces), available here http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=CM_1939__6__1_0, legally I presume.

What he calls the *direct product* is clearly what we understand today as a *tensor product*, while our understanding of the *direct product* is the full (possibly infinite) *Cartesian product* with some *projections*.

I'm interested what is the background for this, was this general usage in the dim and distant past, when did the terminology change and why?

(copied here from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3857681)

Comment: This use of the term “direct product” for tensor products goes back to Murray and von  Neumann in 1936. See my previous question on the notation for tensor products https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7018/first-appearance-of-tensor-product-symbol-otimes and the last paragraph of Section 1 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf.

Comment: Van der Waerden uses "direct product" for tensor product of algebras in Moderne Algebra (1930),  §67.